# Calling xrdb from a remote server to load Xresources files

Tags: x11, display

I have a simple startup script that I want my remote desktop manager (Exceed onDemand) to launch in order to start the i3 window manager on a remote machine.

Here is the script (called `i3start`), it just sets the environment to point to my locally built binaries, loads some Xresources files to set colors and other settings, then finally launch `i3`:

```
#!/bin/bash

_root="${HOME}/.i3wm"

source /etc/environment
export PATH="$_root/usr/bin:${PATH}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$_root/usr/lib:$_root/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
export PERL5LIB="$_root/usr/lib/urxvt"

xrdb $_root/common/themes/solarized-dark/Xresources
xrdb -override ${HOME}/.Xresources
xrdb -q &> ~/xrdb.log

exec i3
```

In Exceed onDemand, I have the following Xstart settings:

- Startup method: Secure Shell
- Host: `<insert_server_name>`
- Authentication: *Use Exceed Connection Server Credentials*
- Command: `/home/user_name/.i3wm/i3start`

I'm not entirely sure (even after reading their user manual) what command these settings yield, but I imagine it does something to start X and then issues `ssh -X <insert_server_name> /home/user_name/.i3wm/i3start`, or something to that effect.

The trouble is -- as confirmed by checking `~/xrdb.log`, which is empty -- those files loaded by `xrdb` take no effect. I also used `xrdb -n` to confirm that the files can be properly parsed by `xrdb`, but it still results in nothing being set in the X resources database.

If I change my Xstart settings to just launch `xterm`:

- Startup method: Secure Shell
- Host: `<insert_server_name>`
- Authentication: *Use Exceed Connection Server Credentials*
- Command: `xterm`

I get a simple terminal, and then after launching the script `/home/user_name/.i3wm/i3start` from `xterm`, everything works as intended with the settings loaded from those 2 Xresources files and shown properly by `xrdb -q`.

In my `i3start` script, is there something I need to do before calling `xrdb` to load those settings? I think it must be something that just launching `xterm` does.

*edit:* Forgot to mention, the remote server is Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial).